# Alternating Series with a Shifted Denominator

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I'm trying to understand the behavior of a finite alternating series for which I have a similar finite alternating series that I know the behavior of.

More formally I know the value of:
$f(X) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k*x_k}{k} $

But I am interested in knowing the value of:
$h(X) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k*x_k}{k+1}$

$x_n$ is a well defined value but grows extremely large (on the order of $10^{80}$). Despite this though, $0\leq f(x) \leq 1$ and experimental results show that $-1 \leq h(x) \leq 1$ as well but I have been unable to prove the bounds on $h(x)$

Are there any standard methods I can use to apply the results I have for $f(x)$ to better understand the behavior of $h(x)$? Also, any resources or theorems to approximate alternating series would extremely helpful. Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this!